# react js add class with css modules

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I am using css modules in my react app

```
import styles from './Timeheader.css'
<div className={styles.hour}>9</div>
```

What is the best way to add class dynamically? Or in react, is it bad idea?

Comment: What'd trigger the class to be added dynamically? A state change? A theme? etc?

Comment: it's for change a  theme